# Applying Affine transform on an image using dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I am looking to align two face images using the 68 landmarks learnt by the dlib detector. I know I can convert the images to OpenCV Mat and then use the `warpAffine` method. I am having certain memory leaks with it and decided to see if using only dlib is possible. I noticed that the dlib library has some methods in `geometry.h` for this purpose.

For this, I am using `find_affine_transform` method to get a `point_transform_affine` object where I find the affine transformation between 3 points obtained using the shape and template. In the documentation, it is written that we can use this object to apply the transformation on vector of points. However, I have been unable to find some example for it.

1. Could you tell me how I can apply the transformation learnt ?
2. Secondly, I have an image loaded in array2d object. Is there a way to go from array2d to vector of points ?

Some initial code is listed down below for the find_affine_transform.

```
std::vector<dlib::vector<double,2>> TemplateLandmarks;
std::vector<dlib::vector<double,2>> ObtainedLandmarks;
// push_back the specific coordinates in the above vectors

array2d<bgr_pixel> img; 
// read the image from a file path using load_image

//  learning the best transformation map
point_transform_affine H = find_affine_transform ( ObtainedLandmarks , TemplateLandmarks );
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also have the same question about a function to apply the transformation matrix over an dlib::array2d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the [extract_image_chips](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#extract_image_chips) function in dlib.  There is even an example of its use in the [face landmarking example program](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) to align faces.

Comment: After some "googling", I found `dlib::transform_image` function in your lib, that seems to be what @NK18 and me were looking for :-)